# After rich:extendedDataTable sortby,otheractions are not getting executed

Tags: richfaces

I have a RichFaces UI which are having sidebar menu and sidebar had 8 links.
I am using Seam @DataModel and @Factory and hibernate criteria to populate all the 8 pages.
In all the pages i have sortby functionality which is working fine.
I am able to get all data in all the 8 pages and I can freely navigate around all the links/xhtmls.
But if in one of the xhtmlpages if I do sorting or groupby after that I am unable to navigate to other pages.If I select any other link the same last query which is executed for sorting is getting executed.
Is this an issue? or do I need add any configuration.
Please help me in solving this issue.
Below is the codesnippet
one of the 8 xhtml

```
        <rich:column sortable="true"
            sortBy="#{p.regionid}" width="100px" label="Region Id">
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Region Id" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{p.regionid}" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column sortable="true"
            sortBy="#{p.region}" width="100px" label="Region Name">
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Region Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{p.region}" />
        </rich:column>
```

Sidebar

Action

```
@DataModel("regions")
private List<CoreRegion> listRegions;

@Factory("regions")
public void getRegions() {
    System.out.println("Inside get Regions");
    Session userDatabase = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Criteria crit = userDatabase.createCriteria(CoreRegion.class);
            listRegions = crit.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved by updating the rich:panelMenuItem by following

```
                <rich:panelMenuItem>
                    <s:link view="/currencyList.xhtml">
                        <h:outputText value="Currency" style="TEXT-DECORATION: none;"></h:outputText>
                    </s:link>
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
```